# angular-bootstrap modal background is not transparent after uglify

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, gulp, uglifyjs, angular-bootstrap

Angular Bootstrap modal is not working correctly in Gulp production mode, but in dev mode it works fine.

[image]

My GULP method which responsible for code compression:

```
gulp.task('scripts-prod', function() {
    return gulp.src(paths.vendorJavascript.concat(paths.appJavascript, paths.appTemplates))
        .pipe(plugins.if(/html$/, buildTemplates()))
        .pipe(plugins.concat('app.js'))
        .pipe(plugins.ngAnnotate())
        .pipe(plugins.uglify({
            mangle: {
                except: ['angular', 'angular-bootstrap']
            }
        }))
        .pipe(plugins.rev())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.publicJavascript))
        .pipe(plugins.rev.manifest({path: 'rev-manifest.json'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.publicJavascript));
});
```

I have also tried to use uglify like this

```
.pipe(plugins.uglify({
                mangle: false
            }))
```

and without parameters

```
.pipe(plugins.uglify())
```

but modal still do not work correctly.

My project's Gulp code logic is based on this tutorial http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/10/working-with-a-laravel-4-plus-angular-application/

Maybe can someone say how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you maybe missing to copy  a css in your production gulp task?

Comment: No, I haven't missed to do that.

Comment: What does inspect element (in chrome) says about the css rules aplying to the modal? Can you see your rule there?

Comment: Yup, the problem was with css. Thank you

Comment: :) happy to see you solved!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for helping solve this problem. The problem was with CSS file which was not removed before minimising all CSS files, and unnecessary code was included to the final CSS.

Answer (score 1):

There are some forms of angular dependency injection which are broken by uglify. Take a look at this and see if it is related to your problems: http://thegreenpizza.github.io/2013/05/25/building-minification-safe-angular.js-applications/